# Not able to redirect to another method of controller in Spring MVC using path variable

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have one controller class, in which I have two methods. I am submitting a form from jsp ,then control is coming in first method, from first method I am redirecting to second method using path variable, but Its not working.

Below is my code:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

 @RequestMapping(value = "saveUserDetails", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveUser(ModelMap map, HttpSession session,HttpServletRequest request) {
    String strId= request.getParameter("userId");;
    return "redirect:userView/" + strId;
}


 @RequestMapping(value="userView/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String displayUser(@PathVariable String id, Model model) {
    System.out.println("in method2");
    return "showUser";
}

}
```

When user submits the form from jsp then control comes into saveUser() method, there I am redirecting to another method displayUser(), but due to some reason Its not working. 
Could anybody please help me ?

Comment: Describe _not working_.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : I have put debug points displayUser() method, the control is not coming in this method.

Comment: What is happening? Where is your browser trying to redirect you to? What url? What do Spring logs show?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Its not giving any error or logs, however the url in the browser is http://localhost/UserApp/userView/9625 and page is not completely rendering.

Comment: Again, what does _page is not completely rendering_. Is it rendering "a bit"? Not at all? Enable debug logging and check what Spring is doing. Please be clear and update your question with those relevant details.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis- Its remain on the current page but url is getting changed as said above. And current page's images, css are not rendering completely.

Answer (score -1):

You missed **/** before userView.

```
return "redirect:/userView/" + strId;
```

check spring documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html)

Comment: What is the relevance of `RedirectAttributes` javadoc here? Why do they need the `/`?